# Debezium ExtractNewRecordState transformation delete not working

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

I am using Debezium Postgres Connector to fetch CDC data and using unwrap transform to extract the main row value before posting data to Kafka

But for Delete its just posting the PK and not all the columns

Any ideas or someone who faced similar issue?

Below is the config:

```
"transforms": "unwrap",
"transforms.unwrap.add.fields": "op",
"transforms.unwrap.delete.handling​.mode": "rewrite",
"transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
"transforms.unwrap.tombstones.on.delete": "false", 
"transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState"
```

Also Postgres table is set to FULL Replica Identity